# How do I get a glowing line via textures or materials?

Tags: materials, texturing

I've created objects that use the Halo material but it has a vertex glow. How would I make a whole line glow without dividing my surface into an absurdly large number of vertices?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to do this relatively easily and for certain edges, select the appropriate faces in edit mode and click EDIT->Mesh->Faces->Wire Frame on a duplicate of your original model.

Assign new materials with emission. I recommend just doing a solid material and join the models back together (I really usually work in Cycles, and if doing so you can use a simple Emission shader since Blender Internal doesn't really like emitting from materials in my experience). This adds a few vertices, depending on how smooth you want your outlines to be, but I've found that usually they can be pretty simple. You wind up with something like this:

[image: And here's a sample render out, combined with a look at my emission shader that makes it go.]

Comment: Do notice that this adds vertices, but I've found it to be the quickest way by far to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 13):

This is something that I saw today that is kind of interesting.

Take your model, and UV unwrap it normally.

Duplicate the UV unwrapping, and click UV Unwrap->Reset on this second UV unwrap (check the far right of the image below and you'll see if you did this right)

Create nodes as follows for your material:

[image: Example node setup.]
*Note that the UV values correlate to R and G above.*

This solution adds no extra geometry, and handles subdivision well (if you do it, however, remember to un-check "Subdivide UV" in the modifier or you'll get issues). You can adjust thresholds by moving the Greater Than math functions closer/further to or from 0 or 1.

I mostly based my setup off of this tutorial from TheBlenderNerd (to the point where I even used the same thresholds!), which can be helpful if you want to figure out what exactly I did, or if you run into an issue with forming the UV maps.

Here it is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjhdGY21WqQ

Comment: Combine this with your other answer if you don't mind. It's generally not good practice to have multiple answers by the same person on the Stack Exchange. Does look interesting to be sure.

Comment: They're too different to combine; there's a reason they have the multiple answer thing, and that's because something like this lumped in with the geometry modifying one would be confusing.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is different depending upon whether you are using the Cycles render engine or the Blender Internal render engine.

- Cycles: Select your object and go into edit
  mode. From that screen, select each of the edges you want to glow,
  then go to the materials menu and assign them an 'emissions'
  material. This is probably not only the easiest way to handle glow,
  but also will produce the nicest results.
- Blender Internal: First,
  duplicate your shape: one of the copies will serve as your
  object-proper, and the other one will produce the glow. Select one of
  these, and apply a subsurface division to it. Now go into edit mode
  and apply loop cuts on every side, sliding them up so that they lie
  very near to the actual edges of the object. Optimally, you should be
  able to get these loop cuts close enough to the edge that when you
  zoom back out and go into object mode, it should look almost as sharp
  as the original shape. However, by doing this, the other copy of the
  object should be just peeking through the object along every edge.
  Select the other shape, and shrink it down ever so slightly (maybe a
  factor of .995 or so) so that it fits snugly inside the first shape.
  Finally, you should go to the material menu and assign the inner
  object a material, then go down to the 'Shading' options and increase
  the Emission value. If everything is sized properly, then the edges
  should have a nice glow.

With either of these options, you can always use either the compositor, or an external editing program (like GIMP or Photoshop) to enhance these effects.

Comment: "select each of the edges ... and assign them an 'emissions' material" AFAIK, you can only assign materials to faces, and even if you could assign them to edges they would only be visible if the sample happened to hit *exactly* on the edge (which may not even be possible due to flop rounding).

Answer (score 2):

A material/texture approach wouldn't be best for this application for the reason you stated, as well as the problem of it not being able to shine light. I would use a combination of a Cycles emission material and compositing to blur the object. This will allow the material to actually shine light; while compositing adds the glowing effect. For a non-glowing fuzzy line, a hair particle system would work in many cases.

Comment: He wants it via textures or materials, not post-processing.